# How can i play google playstore games on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: google

It says that i can install a google play downloader on ubuntu 14.04? but wont install! So i can install and play google play store games on my pc. Thank you

Comment: I don't think Google Play games can run on Ubuntu. GPlay games don't even run in ChromeOS , and that's also a Google product. I believe you would have more luck with Windows games, which you can play under Wine in Ubuntu. Android an ChromeOS are special breeds of linux, they don't mix with 'the others' at the playground. Shame on Google! You can play Gplay games on PC ... if you install Androidx86 on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Google Play Downloader" sounds to me like something that just grabs the APKs, not something that allows you to run them. Seeing as you just say "it says" and no what "it" is, that's the most I can assume.

If you want to run Android apps on Ubuntu, you'll need an emulator. Something like Genymotion.

http://techapple.net/2014/05/5-best-android-emulators-linux-run-android-apps-linux-ubuntulinuxmintfedoraarchlinuxopensusemageiacentos-etc/